# How to configure a SCSS project?

Tags: ruby, sass

I'm pretty new to SASS/SCSS and got a git project with CSS Files in the main directory which shall import partials from a subdirectory. I was wondering if it's possible to install sass on the server, create a compass project so that css files will be created automatically after a live edit of the scss files on the server? Or does it have to be local with a filewatcher? I already tried to set up a compass project on the server but no css files were created automatically. Was it because of wrong settings or is it just not possible this way?

If it's possible is there a good step by step tutorial? I already found [this](http://thesassway.com/beginner/getting-started-with-sass-and-compass)

Maybe the problem is the path. In my config.rb I changed the path without knowing what to write in the string if sass and css directory are the same as project path. Didn't work with "/" or an empty string.

Comment: Did you try reading the installation instructions for either Sass or Compass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Sass and Compass provide watch commands. You can use either:

```
sass --watch input.scss:output.css (options)
```

or, assuming you've got your Compass config file correctly setting your css_dir vairable:

```
compass watch
```

Either of those should recompile the css file upon changes. If you want this done live on the server, you'll need to execute the watch command on the server.

Comment: ok thanks. I tried sass --watch my_filename.scss:my_filename.css --style compressed in the directory where the main.css is that imports several partials from a sub directory. But it can't read my _colors.scss (error message: file to import not found or unreadable). But it already worked local in php storm. In that file are just some color variables. It's the first file that's imported. No css file is created. May because it doesn't compile after that error but I dont know why there is this error because it already worked local...

Comment: oh sorry, had a typo. input and output name has to be the same. Now it works! Thx again! :)

Answer (score 0):

To add a point to @aerook's answer, 
In your projects you may have multiple scss and css files. In which case you may use the following to watch the entire scss directory to make changes in the css directory

> sass --watch scss:css

PS : scss and css are folder names in the same directory path.